# Do loop is stuck at the first subarray in MPI SCATTER and GATHER

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have two arrays, array `global` has 8 values and it will be scatter among array `local` with 2 values. What I was trying to do is, *take the big array, split into small arrays, do some work, then put it back together.*

Problem:
Even though I successfully scattered the data, the `do` loop as written is only working for the first sub array `local`. What I want is all of the integers in the scattered `local` array should be multiplied by 2, then gathered into the `global` array.

Code for the do loop (some work has been done here):

```
do j = 1,2
  local(j) = j*2
  print *, j
end do
```

Here's the full code. If you go down below you'll notice the part which I need your help.

```
MODULE MPI
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INCLUDE   'mpif.h'
    INTEGER   :: MYID,TOTPS, IERR, MPISTTS

CONTAINS 

    SUBROUTINE MPIINIT
        IMPLICIT NONE
        CALL MPI_INIT( IERR ) 
        CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,MYID,IERR)
        CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,TOTPS,IERR)
    RETURN
    END SUBROUTINE MPIINIT
END MODULE MPI

PROGRAM SCATTER 
    USE MPI
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    CALL MPIINIT
    CALL TEST
    CALL  MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)

CONTAINS 

SUBROUTINE TEST
    USE MPI 
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    INTEGER :: I,J
    INTEGER,DIMENSION(8) :: GLOBAL
    INTEGER,DIMENSION(2) :: LOCAL 

    if (myid .eq. 0) then 
    do i = 1,8
    global(i) = i
    end do 
    end if

    call mpi_scatter(global,2,mpi_integer,local,2,mpi_integer,0, &
    mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    print*,"task",myid,":",local
    call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)

    !!!!!!! do some work here
    do j = 1,2
    local(j) = j*2
    print*,j
    end do
    !!!!!! end work 


    call mpi_gather(local,2,mpi_integer,global,2,mpi_integer,0, &
    mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    if(myid .eq. 0) then
    print*,"task",myid,":",global
    end if
END SUBROUTINE TEST
END PROGRAM SCATTER
```

Notes:

(1) I've been reading & learning from [this](http://goo.gl/BPUvHi) thread but it looks challenging for now.
(2) Run code `mpif90 SCATTER.f90` .. `mpirun -np 4 ./a.out`

Output:

```
    task 0 : 1 2
    task 1 : 3 4
    task 2 : 5 6
    task 3 : 7 8
    1
    2
    1
    2
    1
    2
    1
    2
   task 0 : 2 4 2 4 2 4 2 4
```

What I want to get is: `task 0 : 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16`

Comment: I agree with Mark, we especially miss the expected and observed behaviour. What is wrong? Where is the problem?

Comment: gotcha, I am editing it now

Comment: It is still not clear! what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```
local(j) = j * 2
print*, j
```

I don't think that does what you think it does.

You probably meant to write

```
local(j) = local(j) * 2
print*, local(j)
```